# Links regarding connecting to the database of another laptop or desktop from my latop/desktop

Tags: c#, sql-server

can any post any links on how to connect to the database of another laptop/workstation from my workstation, the database im using is sql server 2008

I will be needing links on how to connect to other database via wifi or router and lan cable. I need to expand my knowledge in developing software in c#. Thanks

Comment: Honestly, you could have searched for this rather than posting a new question. Look for **connection string** settings on MSDN. As for information on networking components - SO is not the place for that. Further, it has almost nothing to do with software development in general.

Comment: Thanks sorry im just starting to develop @yuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example string for connecting C# entity framework application to an SQL server anywhere on the network:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="xyzEntities" 
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=NAMEOFYOURSERVERCOMPUTER;initial catalog=xyz;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

It does not matter if you want to connect via WIFI, "router", or LAN cable. The procedure is exactly the same.

You need to configure the SQL server you want to connect to to allow remote connections, and also you need to configure the windows firewall on the computer where the SQL server is running to allow connections to the SQL server ports.

And if you have other firewalls or whatever you need to configure those too so that you are able to connect to the SQL server ports from your local computer.

Comment: I see its almost the same as connecting my application to my localhost. Thanks @dontomaso